# Unable to delete domain shared contacts using GAE Java API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-contacts-api

I am trying to write an application that adds/updates/deletes domain shared contacts in to Google using Java API.

I am getting following exception while I try to delete the created contact from Google.

No authentication header information

```
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
    at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96)
    at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.<init>(AuthenticationException.java:67)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:543)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:515)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:515)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.delete(Service.java:1560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.delete(GoogleService.java:691)
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseEntry.delete(BaseEntry.java:647)
    at com.visy.connector.synchronizer.impl.ContactSynchronizerImpl.deleteContact(ContactSynchronizerImpl.java:170)
    at com.visy.connector.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Following is the code I am using for deleteContact

```
public String deleteContact(String contactId) {

        String resultString = "Failed"
        ContactEntry contactEntry = getContactFromGoogle(contactId);
        try {
              if (contactEntry != null) {
              // deleting contact from Google
               contactEntry.delete();
               resultString = "Sucess";
        } catch (IOException e) {
             LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
             LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        }
        return resultString;
    }


         public ContactEntry getContactFromGoogle(String contactId) {
        ContactEntry contact = null;
        ContactsService myService = getOAuthContactService("getContact");
        try {
            String urlStr =      
                              http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mydomain/full
                              + "/" + contactId 
                              + "?xoauth_requestor_id=" + domainAdminEmail;
              contact = myService.getEntry(new URL(urlStr), 
                                          ContactEntry.class);
                        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        }
        return contact;
    }

         public ContactsService getOAuthContactService(String serviceName) {
        final ContactsService myService = new ContactsService(serviceName);
        GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
        oauthParameters.setScope(Scope);
        oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(ConsumerKey);
        oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(secret);                      OAuthSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();
        try {
            myService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, signer);
        } catch (OAuthException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Created the Authenticated Contact Service");
        return myService;
    }
```

In above code getContactFromGoogle() method is returning the appropriate contact (as per the logs and debug results). But when I invoke contactEntry.delete(), the "No Authentication Header Information" exception is thrown.

Kindly help me to figure out what may have been wrong with the code.

Regards,
Nirzari

Answer (score 1):

By using myService.setCredentials(username,password)  usermail or domainAdminMail Password

There are more 3 methods you can use any by using (username,password, token) 
check it......

this code before catch() block

```
{
     ContactsService myService = getOAuthContactService("getContact");
       try{
             String urlStr =http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mydomain/full
                          + "/" + contactId 
                          + "?xoauth_requestor_id=" + domainAdminEmail;

               myService.setCredentials(username,password);

          contact = myService.getEntry(new URL(urlStr), 
                                      ContactEntry.class);
                    }
    }
```